# Benefits of using dependency injection Spring

Tags: java, spring

What are the benefits of dependency injection of spring in an application?

Can i achieve the dependency injection without using Spring as a framework?

Comment: @TheLostMind Martic Fowler was not an author on the Design Patterns book :)

Comment: @TheLostMind Happens to everyone :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Yes,** you can achieve dependancy injection without using spring framework.
by using **`Java interfaces`.**

1)Minimizes the amount of code in your application.

2)Make your application more testable by not requiring any singletons or JNDI lookup mechanisms in your unit test cases.

3)Loosely couple code.

4)Separation of responsibility.

5)Configuration and code is separate.

6) when you use it, you will get to know lots of benefits..........

Comment: http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/SpringDependencyInjection/article.html check it out

Answer (score 1):

Dependency injection has many benefits like,

- It Reduces code Dependencies
- Reduces Dependency Carrying
- Can achieve reusable,testable and redable Code
- Less boiler plate code
- loose coupling with interfaces
- Can separate out configuration and the code
- Can improve application testing with Mock objects
- Code maintenance is easy
- Clear, simple and ready design and architecture contracts

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Guice](https://github.com/google/guice), a lightweight dependency injection framework for Java 5 and above, brought to you by Google.